# Where can I get the Windows 10 upgrade advisor?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-10-preview

[BillOer](https://superuser.com/users/327156/billoer) mentioned at [Windows 10 Upgrade and Junctions](https://superuser.com/q/922478/370921)

> the Windows 10 upgrade advisor

Where can I get that standalone upgrade advisor exe, either compatible with all Windows versions or selectable (e.g. from a list) for different previous Windows versions (e.g. XP, Vista, 7)? There were such upgrade advisors for upgrades to Windows 7 and to 8 (and/or 8.1), which checked the compatibility of the hardware and of the installed software with the respective version of the operating system. (I do not want to upgrade and *then* find out that my hard- and/or software is not compatible with Win 10.)

Comment: Advisor is built into KB3035583, it will put a "get windows 10" icon in the system tray, you can check compatibility using that. It will run a readiness report and flag anything that has issues with W10.

Comment: @Moab: Where can I get KB3035583 for Win XP 32bit?

Comment: Roel is correct there is no upgrade path from XP to 10, so no KB 3035583 for xp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not upgrade from XP to 10, so there is no such upgrade advisor. See e.g. http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-win_upgrade/i-want-to-reserve-my-free-copy-of-windows-10-but-i/848b5cce-958b-49ae-a132-a999a883265b?auth=1 where it discusses that a prerequisite for the upgrade app is 'at least Windows 7 SP1 or Windows 8.1 Update'.

The windows 10 upgrade advisor checks minimal hardware requirements and compatibility (drivers).

Comment: While the question is tagged Windows XP, it is arguably a general question about upgrading from any previous version of Windows.  It would be good to know whether or not such an app exists for Windows 7 and 8.1.